# Remove text but not appended element from parent element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove some menu text, created by a plugin, with javascript. The menu text is next to a image which shares the same `a` tag. So I just want to see and click the menu image.

The generated code

```
<li id="menu-item-15" class="qtranxs-lang-menu qtranxs-lang-menu-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-15">
  <a title="English" href="#">Lang:&nbsp;<img src="http://maisha.dev/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/gb.png" alt="English" /></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="qtranxs-lang-menu-item qtranxs-lang-menu-item-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a title="English" href="http://maisha.dev/wp/?lang=en"><img src="http://maisha.dev/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/gb.png" alt="English" />&nbsp;English</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="qtranxs-lang-menu-item qtranxs-lang-menu-item-fi menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a title="suomi" href="http://maisha.dev/wp/?lang=fi"><img src="http://maisha.dev/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/fi.png" alt="suomi" />&nbsp;suomi</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Selecting the appropriate element

```
var main_menu_lang_li_tag = document.getElementsByClassName('qtranxs-lang-menu')[0];
var main_menu_lang_a_tag = main_menu_lang_li_tag.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

I can retrieve just the text `Lang:` with

```
main_menu_lang_a_tag.text;
```

or

```
main_menu_lang_a_tag.innerText;
```

but if I try and remove the text,

```
main_menu_lang_a_tag.text = "";
```

the image tag is also removed.

How can I remove the text and not the image tag that follows? **Note:** I cannot really do, delete x number of characters from the start as the text string content is variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by removing all *text nodes* from the element:

```
var child = main_menu_lang_a_tag.firstChild;
var next;
while (child) {
    next = child.nextSibling;
    if (child.nodeType === 3) { // Text node
        main_menu_lang_a_tag.removeChild(child);
    }
    child = next;
}
```

You can also locate the element a bit more easily with `querySelector`:

```
var main_menu_lang_a_tag = document.querySelector(".qtranxs-lang-menu a");
```

Example:

```js
console.log("before...");
setTimeout(function() {
  var main_menu_lang_a_tag = document.querySelector(".qtranxs-lang-menu a");
  var child = main_menu_lang_a_tag.firstChild;
  var next;
  while (child) {
    next = child.nextSibling;
    if (child.nodeType === 3) { // Text node
      main_menu_lang_a_tag.removeChild(child);
    }
    child = next;
  }
  console.log("after");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-15" class="qtranxs-lang-menu qtranxs-lang-menu-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-15">
    <a title="English" href="#">Lang:&nbsp;<img src="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/gb.png" alt="English" /></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-16" class="qtranxs-lang-menu-item qtranxs-lang-menu-item-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16">
        <a title="English" href="http://example.com/wp/?lang=en">
          <img src="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/gb.png" alt="English" />&nbsp;English</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-17" class="qtranxs-lang-menu-item qtranxs-lang-menu-item-fi menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17">
        <a title="suomi" href="http://example.com/wp/?lang=fi">
          <img src="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/fi.png" alt="suomi" />&nbsp;suomi</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

---

Side note: FWIW, what you're referring to with your `main_menu_lang_a_tag` and such variables aren't tags, they're *elements*. Tags are the text notation we use to define elements in HTML source code.

Comment: Thanks. There's just a small type-o in         ```main_menu_lang_a.removeChild(child);``` should be ```main_menu_lang_a_tag.removeChild(child);``` but it's fine in the working example.